# How to add Addepar ember-widgets to EmberCli project?

Tags: ember.js, bower, emblem.js

I want to add Addepar ember-widgets to my project.

I have installed it with `bower install ember-widgets --save`.

During the installation it asked me to chose versions for `jquery`, `ember` and `bootstrap` saying that it can not find the appropriate version.

When I try to use their example from the page

```
handelbars:

{{#carousel-component}}
  {{#carousel-item class="active"}}
    <img src="/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg" alt="">
  {{/carousel-item}}
  {{#carousel-item}}
    <img src="/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-02.jpg" alt="">
  {{/carousel-item}}
  {{#carousel-item}}
    <img src="/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-03.jpg" alt="">
  {{/carousel-item}}
{{/carousel-component}}


emblem:
carousel-component
  carousel-item.active
    img alt='image1' src='/images/hires03.jpg'
  carousel-item
    img alt='image1' src='/images/hires03.jpg'
  carousel-item
    img alt='image1' src='/images/hires03.jpg'
```

I get `Assertion Failed: A helper named 'carousel-component' could not be found`

Did I installed it wrong or I have translated it to emblem wrongly, or something else...

Comment: Did you get this working in the end? Would be helpful to know if you did!

Comment: nope unfortunately not :)